# Splitting created sequence of dates into separate columns

Tags: r, date, posixct

I created a dataframe (Dates) of dates/times every 3 hours from 1981-2010 as follows:

```
# Create dates and times
start <- as.POSIXct("1981-01-01")
interval <- 60
end <- start + as.difftime(10957, units="days")
Dates = data.frame(seq(from=start, by=interval*180, to=end))
colnames(Dates) = "Date"
```

I now want to split the data into four separate columns with year, month, day and hour. I tried so split the dates using the following code:

```
Date.split = strsplit(Dates, "-| ")
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in strsplit(Dates, "-| ") : non-character argument
```

If I try to convert the Dates data to characters then it completely changes the dates, e.g.

```
Dates.char = as.character(Dates)
```

gives the following output:

```
Dates.char Large Character (993.5 kB)
   chr "c(347155200, 347166000 ...
```

I'm getting lost with the conversion between character and numeric and don't know where to go from here. Any insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `format`.

```
head(
  setNames(
    cbind(Dates, 
      format(Dates, "%Y"), format(Dates, "%m"), format(Dates, "%d"),
      format(Dates, "%H")), 
    c("dates", "year", "month", "day", "hour"))
)
                dates year month day hour
1 1981-01-01 00:00:00 1981    01  01   00
2 1981-01-01 03:00:00 1981    01  01   03
3 1981-01-01 06:00:00 1981    01  01   06
4 1981-01-01 09:00:00 1981    01  01   09
5 1981-01-01 12:00:00 1981    01  01   12
6 1981-01-01 15:00:00 1981    01  01   15
```

Comment: This works very cleanly @Andre Wildberg - many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A very concise way is to decompose the POSIXlt record:

```
Dates = cbind(Dates, do.call(rbind, lapply(Dates$Date, as.POSIXlt)))
```

or

```
Dates <- data.frame(Dates, unclass(as.POSIXlt(Dates$Date)))
```

It will return you some aditional data, however. You can filter further

```
#                 Date sec min hour mday mon year wday yday isdst zone # gmtoff
# 1 1981-01-01 00:00:00   0   0    0    1   0   81    4    0     0  -03 # -10800
# 2 1981-01-01 03:00:00   0   0    3    1   0   81    4    0     0  -03 # -10800
# 3 1981-01-01 06:00:00   0   0    6    1   0   81    4    0     0  -03 # -10800
```

Comment: year is base 1900, you must add 1900 to the column.

Comment: Thanks @Ric Villalba - this works nicely. I note month starts at 0 rather than 1 also, so I will add 1 to this column too. Thank you.